# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loading' of 'userUpdate' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, express, redux, jwt

[This is where my variables are defined , i have also attache a detail image of how my variable are used in the second image[][1 i do not understand why it is still claiming that it cannot read property of undefined]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxQFu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The image you supplied does not show any type of destruction. Assuming variables are defined in the file you provided then you shouldn't see the error you described. However, if you are, for instance, destructuring the properties from props those properties were never passed into the component then that is probably why you are getting that error.

The following destructuring will not work inside your current component if you didn't load those properties into the component.

Now inside your component

{loading, error, success} = props //Nope these properties were never passed to props.

Question: where and how are you using the userUpdate object?